# Is there a way to add pipes in Roslaunch files?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So in order to get more information out of GMapping, I had to write a simple publisher to publish what I wanted after I piped it in. My question now is can you add pipes to a Roslaunch file, so that way instead of having to type

roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch | rosrun scan publisher.py

I can just add it to an xml file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39301/is-there-a-way-to-add-pipes-in-roslaunch-files?/) by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-07-19**:
...why not just add the publisher to the GMapping node?

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-07-20**:
Oh, I was having difficulty finding what I wanted in the code, since the Gmapping node is really just a wrapper. It is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch does have a launch-prefix option for nodes. Although it is a prefix, not postfix, you might be able to come up with something like a bash script that automatically pipes.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0